# Remote debug aosp with VSCode

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, native, android-source

I'm trying to use VSCode to debug native cpp code on Android Open Source Project.

I successfull launch gdbserver on my remote target on Android 5, and successfull debug it with gdbclient on my pc.

I would like to launch gdbclient into an IDE to debug easily properly, with IHM, etc...

I'm trying to configure launch.json in VSCode but I keep blocked with json configuration.

My command to lanch the program I want to debug is :

```
adb shell gdbserver :5039 /system/bin/myProgram
```

My command to debug :

```
gdbclient 5039
```

This is an example of configuration of remote debugging :

```
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "???",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "preLaunchTask": "init_gdbclient",
        "miDebuggerPath": "gdbclient",
        "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:5039",
    }
```

The preLaunchTask gdbclient is used to init "gdbclient" command from aosp script.

My question is that :

Why VSCode need the path of the program I want to debug on remote debugging ?

I expected only ip/port configuration. I think this is enough for client side, right ?

Answer (score 0):

The gdb program (or something else playing that role) on the build machine needs visibility to an *unstripped* version of the target program being proxy debugged through gdbserver in order to do meaningful symbolic lookup of the functions and structures in the program being debugged.  Preferably the build machine copy is not only unstripped, but included debug information as well.

It should generally be possible to launch a debug session without this, however you will be wading through unsymbolized hex addresses and data, so it will be unusually challenging to figure out what you are looking at.

You might find it informative to run gdb on the command line and get a sense of how things work underneath the IDE/GUI facade.